# Back-converting from JSON draft 4 to JSON draft 3

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a bit of a weird situation.  I am running a JSON schema validator that doesn't support draft 4, and due to corporate wonkiness I'm stuck with it instead of replacing it.  Our developers are giving me schemas in draft 4 format, so I have to go through by hand and back-convert it, particularly the required fields.

This has all worked fine up until I hit something like this (consider this pseudo-code; I'm still getting the hang of JSON):

```
    "items": {
        "type": "array",
        "required" : true,
        "items": [ 
              {...},
              "required": ["0", "1"]  // This bit right here
        ],
    }
```

I'm told it basically says, "The first two items in the array are required."  But I can't find a way to express that in JSON draft 3.  Is that even supported, and if so, how would you express it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`required` is a keyword that only has meaning for object instances, not for arrays.

The way to indicate that an array must have at least 2 items is through `minItems` keyword in both [Draft3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03#section-5.5) and [Draft4](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html).

If you need to express any other schema just for the first and second item in an array, you do it by having two schemas in the `items` array. For instance, the following schema requires that properties `"0"` and `"1"` are included in the first and second items in the array.

For Draft 3:

```
"items" : [{
        "properties" : {
            "0" : {"required" : true},
            "1" : {"required" : true}
        }
    }, {
        "properties" : {
            "0" : {"required" : true},
            "1" : {"required" : true}
        }
    }
]
```

And Draft 4:

```
"items" : [{
        "required" : ["0", "1"]
    }, {
        "required" : ["0", "1"]
    }
]
```